# Strange NSFormatter behavior

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have TextField with value binded to Document's serverAddress property (readwrite, copy), and TextField `formatter` delegate connected with `ServerAddressFormatter` object in **XIB**.

It's actually working with input like `127.0.0.1:8080`, but as soon as I put something without `:` TextField clear itself completely.

Here's `ServerAddressFormatter` implementation:

```
@implementation ServerAddressFormatter

- (NSString *) stringForObjectValue:(NSArray *)obj {
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        return [obj componentsJoinedByString:@":"];
    } else {
        return @"";
    }
}

- (BOOL)getObjectValue:(out id *)anObject
             forString:(NSString *)string
      errorDescription:(out NSString **)error {
    int i;
    for (i = (int) ([string length] == 0 ? 0 : [string length] - 1); i > 0; i--) {
        if ([string characterAtIndex:i] == ':') break;
    }

    if (i == 0) {
        *anObject = @[string]; // if I put string, @"100" here it's working fine
    } else {
        *anObject = @[[string substringToIndex:i], [string substringFromIndex:i+1]];
    }

    return YES;
}
@end
```

Comment: Can you add `NSLog(@"class = %@", obj.class);` above the `if` in `stringForObjectValue`? What is the output?

Comment: NSCFConstantString first and bunch of NSArray after. If I enter :-less value there's only more NSArray's being printed out.

Comment: Can you add the two lines 'NSLog(@"class = %@", obj.class);` and `NSLog(@"obj = %@", obj);` post the output as an update to your question? Please try with input with ':' and without ':'. Thanks